# Runnig jar dependant java class file

Tags: java, class, jar, cp

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

I have a java program which is dependant on two jar files.
i compile the program using command :

`javac -classpath jar1.jar:jar2.jar myprog.java` and it compiles successfully.

But when i try to run the program using command  : `java -cp jar1.jar:jar2.jar myprog` , it is throwing the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` . please help , where am i wrong ?

i am using ubuntu 10.04.

Actual error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: userapps/SelectionTask_classes/SelectionTask
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: userapps.SelectionTask_classes.SelectionTask
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: userapps/SelectionTask_classes/SelectionTask. Program will exit.
```

where SelectionTask is my class file generated after successful compilation.

Comment: Are the .jar files in the same directory as the compiled classes / executable? If not, you need to specify the absolute / relative path to those .jar files.

Comment: yes , i have specified the absolute path to both the jars ..!
actual command i am running is :

java -cp hadoop-0.20.1-core.jar:lib/hadoopdb.jar userapps/SelectionTask_classes/SelectionTask

Comment: may be this link might give you some idea...

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Comment: eh? I think most of us know what a NoClassDefFoundError means. :) It almost certainly means you are not specifying your classpath currently.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the current directory is also in the classpath. Try running with:

```
java -cp .:jar1.jar:jar2.jar myprog
```

if your compiled class file `myprog.class` is in the current directory.

(This assumes that your program is not in a package).

Comment: same error ! I am specifying the full path to my class file .
java -cp hadoop-0.20.1-core.jar:lib/hadoopdb.jar userapps/SelectionTask_classes/SelectionTask.class. However adding current directory to classpath was useless.

Comment: @AbhishekSagar In that commandline you posted above I don't see you adding the current directory `.` to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add directory where your compiled java program (*.class) file is located. If it's in current directory then you could run it like this (notice "." which denotes current working directory):

```
java -cp .:jar1.jar:jar2.jar myprog
```

Comment: java -cp userapps/SelectionTask_classes:hadoop-0.20.1-core.jar:lib/hadoopdb.jar userapps/SelectionTask_classes/SelectionTask.class

where
 userapps/SelectionTask_classes - is the dir where my class file is.
still same error .

Comment: @AbhishekSagar, that's incorrect. Please look at the documentation for the "java" command and it's command line parameters. You MUST specify the NAME of the JAR file and the DIRECTORY of the CLASS file, and not the path to an actual class file.

Comment: so your command is not working again ! There you specified dir , but java usage is popping up in the terminal.
i tried :

java -cp hadoop-0.20.1-core.jar:lib/hadoopdb.jar:userapps/SelectionTask_classes/ userapps/SelectionTask_classes/ 
(i remove the name of the class file , but same error .)

Comment: java -cp hadoop-0.20.1-core.jar:lib/hadoopdb.jar:userapps/SelectionTask_classes/ myprog

Comment: Thanks a lot , i have resolved this error. Thankful to you brother! :p

java -cp hadoop-0.20.1-core.jar:lib/hadoopdb.jar:userapps/SelectionTask_classes/ myprog –


    Worked !!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error, it's complaining about not being able to find "userapps.SelectionTask_classes.SelectionTask", which hints at the last entry in your classpath not beign specified correctly. Now, assuming that the JAR files you have specified are in the following directory structure:

./hadoop-0.20.1-core.jar

./lib/hadoopdb.jar

./userapps/SelectionTask_classes/

You would run:

```
java -cp hadoop-0.20.1-core.jar:lib/hadoopdb.jar:userapps/SelectionTask_classes/ myprog
```

Comment: I tried your command , it is showing the following :


Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
...and whole manual of using java option.

Comment: java -cp hadoop-0.20.1-core.jar:lib/hadoopdb.jar:userapps/SelectionTask_classes/ userapps/SelectionTask_classes/SelectionTask.class

Comment: Do NOT specify the full path to the class file. As I have mentioned repeatedly, only specify the full paths to the JAR files. For CLASS files, you only need to specify the directory that contains the class files. So, the last entry in your command above is unnecessary.